# Unwanted spacing in bibliography entry / white space in reference

Tags: spacing, bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

EDIT:after fixing the first problem with Harish Kumar's renewcommand, this problem came up:
[image]

I have a problem with the "white spaces" which are produced in the bibliography. I've found a couple of answers but i had the mentioned packages in my preamble before. So those answers wouldn't help. i use \usepackage{url} etc.

The strange thing about my problem is, that it only appears in one entry. i checked a dozen times if there are any differences, but i couldn't find anything. I'm not sure if my MWE will help because there is no white space in there.

[image]

Here's the link for the download of the .bib file for the entries and .bst for the bibstyle.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/09rewicos64zek6/AACFnng5VBKi2r7KP8W99ZvDa?dl=0

Here's my MWE (problem about the MWE, it works):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0mm}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,~}

\begin{document}

\chapter{it doesn't work yet}
blabla \cite{Berger2012}\\
blabla \cite{Klein2013}\\
blabla \cite{Keilig2002}\\
blabla \cite{Jahn2013}\\

\setlength{\bibsep}{2ex plus2ex minus.5ex}
\bibliographystyle{iwbdiss_2} 
\bibliography{literaturverzeichnis}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would adding `\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z\do\1\do\2\do\3\do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\/\do\-\do\_\do\:\do\.}` in the preamble help?

Comment: ^^YES, thanks! first when i copied it into the preamble it didn't work. copy/ paste puts four question marks into your command, for no reason. after deleting those question marks it works fine!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `url` to break the lines at places you want by adding these lines to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do‌​\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\‌​A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q‌​\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z\do\1\do\2\do\3\do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\‌​do\8\do\9\do\/\do\-\do\_\do\:\do\.}
```

This should solve the problem of `url` not being able to split the word `Serienproduktion` in your url.

Comment: Do you have any additonal solutions? The problem that you see in the picture looks great. But sadly another url in my bib has a white space at the end of the line. The word that gets split is: /Vibromet       ers/OFV

So the used letters are within the renewcommand :(
I'll add a picture so it's clear.

Comment: @goodstuff: ` [obeyspaces,spaces]` option is responsible for allowing line break at spaces. If you have enabled it, remove.

Comment: the only thing i've enabled is \usepackage{setspace}.
the line break is not set at a space, is it? it's in between the url and the word "Vibromet \\ers"